# Receiving Runtime Error nullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have this code albumsactivity extend listactivity. what im trying to do is to enable to click on the imgClick image which is set to clickable on an item in a list to show a popupmenu but i get an runtime exception nullpointerexception. please help me fix this

```
@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "ViewHolder" })
public class AlbumsActivity extends ListActivity {
    ConnectionDetector cd;

    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> albumsList;


    JSONArray albums = null;        
    EditText inputSearch;
    ImageView imgClick;
    SimpleAdapter adapter = null;       

    private static final String URL_ALBUMS = "http://api.androidhive.info/songs/album.php";

    // ALL JSON node names
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_SONGS_COUNT = "songs_count";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_albums);

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        // Check for internet connection
        if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            alert.showAlertDialog(AlbumsActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                    "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
            return;
        }

        albumsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
         inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

            inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                    AlbumsActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs.toString());  
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                        int arg3) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                }
            });
        new LoadAlbums().execute();

    ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // on selecting a single album
                // TrackListActivity will be launched to show tracks inside the album
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TrackListActivity.class);

                // send album id to tracklist activity to get list of songs under that album
                String album_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.album_id)).getText().toString();
                i.putExtra("album_id", album_id);               

                startActivity(i);
            }
        });     

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_albums, null);
        imgClick = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.row_click_imageView1);

        imgClick.setOnClickListener(viewClickListener);

    }

    OnClickListener viewClickListener = new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            showPopupMenu(v);
        }
    };

    private void showPopupMenu(View v){
        PopupMenu pop = new PopupMenu(AlbumsActivity.this, v);
        pop.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,pop.getMenu());

        pop.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem arg0) {
                Toast.makeText(AlbumsActivity.this, arg0.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }
            });
        pop.show();
    }




    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == 2){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            String message = data.getStringExtra("Message");
            TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
            text.setText(message);
            }
        }
    }
    class LoadAlbums extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AlbumsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_ALBUMS, "GET",
                    params);

            Log.d("Albums JSON: ", "> " + json);

            try {               
                albums = new JSONArray(json);

                if (albums != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < albums.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = albums.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String songs_count = c.getString(TAG_SONGS_COUNT);

                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put(TAG_SONGS_COUNT, songs_count);

                        albumsList.add(map);
                    }
                }else{
                    Log.d("Albums: ", "null");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }


            pDialog.dismiss();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {


                    AlbumsActivity.this.adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AlbumsActivity.this, albumsList, R.layout.list_item_albums, new String[] { TAG_ID, TAG_NAME, TAG_SONGS_COUNT }, new int[] {R.id.album_id, R.id.album_name, R.id.songs_count });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(AlbumsActivity.this.adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

The logcat is :

```
    09-24 04:05:48.381: E/Trace(3812): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    09-24 04:05:49.761: D/dalvikvm(3812): GC_CONCURRENT freed 147K, 10% free 2659K/2936K, paused 21ms+7ms, total 157ms
    09-24 04:05:49.901: D/AndroidRuntime(3812): Shutting down VM
    09-24 04:05:49.901: W/dalvikvm(3812): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
    09-24 04:05:49.921: E/AndroidRuntime(3812): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    09-24 04:05:49.921: E/AndroidRuntime(3812): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.projectsoftware/com.projectsoftware.AlbumsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    09-24 04:05:49.921: E/AndroidRuntime(3812):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
    09-24 04:05:49.921: E/AndroidRuntime(3812):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    09-24 04:05:49.921: E/AndroidRuntime(3812):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    09-24 04:05:49.921: E/AndroidRuntime(3812):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    09-24 04:05:49.921: E/AndroidRuntime(3812):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    09-24 04:05:49.921: E/AndroidRuntime(3812):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    09-24 04:05:49.921: E/AndroidRuntime(3812):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    09-24 04:05:49.921: E/AndroidRuntime(3812):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    09-24 04:05:49.921: E/AndroidRuntime(3812):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    09-24 04:05:49.921: E/AndroidRuntime(3812):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    09-24 04:05:49.921: E/AndroidRuntime(3812):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    09-24 04:05:49.921: E/AndroidRuntime(3812):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    09-24 04:05:49.921: E/AndroidRuntime(3812): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    09-24 04:05:49.921: E/AndroidRuntime(3812):     at com.projectsoftware.AlbumsActivity.onCreate(AlbumsActivity.java:147)
    09-24 04:05:49.921: E/AndroidRuntime(3812):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    09-24 04:05:49.921: E/AndroidRuntime(3812):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    09-24 04:05:49.921: E/AndroidRuntime(3812):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    09-24 04:05:49.921: E/AndroidRuntime(3812):     ... 11 more
```

## List Item XML

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#d3d6db"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner"
            android:orientation="horizontal"  >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/flag"
                android:layout_width="68dp"
                android:layout_height="68dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

                  <TextView
                android:id="@+id/album_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:ems="8"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#333333" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/album_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Some Item"
                android:lines="1"
                android:ems="8"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#333333" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:clickable="true" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/row_click_imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/popup" />


              <TextView
                android:id="@+id/songs_count"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:lines="1"
                android:ems="8"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#333333" />



            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your **imgClick is NULL**. initialize it as `imgClick= findViewById(R.id.ur_image_id);`

Comment: how do i change or fix this?

Comment: i have initialized it as imgClick = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.row_click_imageView1); in the above code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code to handle on click listner :

```
imgClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // your code

            }
        });
```

> the layout set on onCreate is activity_albums but the id of imgClick is on the layout list_item_albums.

The layout you inflate in `OnCreate` must be having the same ImageView on which you want to handle the `Click`

So you can use this code :

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
 View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_albums, null);
 imgClick = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.row_click_imageView1);
```

Comment: the layout set on onCreate is activity_albums but the id of imgClick is on the layout list_item_albums.

Comment: Are you inflating the same layout or different ??

Comment: im inflating another layout. because activity_albums layout contains the listview and the list_item_albums layout contains the content that i want to be displayed in the listview

Comment: Then the image click can be handled in `getView` of the List Adapter

Comment: how do i achieve the getView of ListAdapter? i really dunno

Comment: try with `imgClick = (ImageView)inflater.findViewById(R.id.row_click_imageView1);` and let me know..

Comment: it says The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type LayoutInflater

Comment: when i clicked the imgClick it doesnt do anything

Comment: just keep a toast and check whether is it going in onClick

Comment: its still not clickable

Comment: Better you extend `Acitivity`and create a Custom Adapter..It will be easy for you to handle list item's `ImageView click` .. You can follow [this](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92)

Comment: Can i see your list item's xml ?? there must be problem with focus

Comment: ive posted my xml. please check

Comment: add this line to your parent `LinearLayout` : `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" `

Comment: should put in on all linear layout or just the top most linearlayout?

Comment: Still no use. not clicking

Comment: Sorry right now busy with my task...Try with this for now - " Better you extend Acitivity and create a Custom Adapter..It will be easy for you to handle list item's ImageView click"...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
imgClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        showPopupMenu(v);
    }
});
```

Comment: This answer doesn't make any difference.